# Drupal 6.x Using Javascript to determine if user is Logged In

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, drupal

I have a situation where I need to use JavaScript on a Drupal 6.x node. I am looking at a JavaScript call to a PHP function, but i'm not exactly sure how to implement it as I'm doing the following:

I have a Java Applet served up from my Drupal site. I want to know if the user is still logged into the site after x minutes. If user is not logged in, I need to close the applet. If the user is still logged in, then I wait another x minutes and check.

I'm looking for code to run on the same page that launched the Java Applet, I can't make changes to the Applet code itself.  Perhaps there is a better way, but I think I need Javascript to perform this continual check using the Javascript "SetTimeout()" method.

How do I call the Drupal PHP "user_is_logged_in()" function from Javascript?

Is there a tutorial that someone might recommend that would help illuminate this process? I've viewed a number of AJAX oriented tutorials, thinking AJAX is what I need to use, but haven't found any that provide a framework to which I can relate.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

not sure about the checking once in x minutes, but there's a method named [drupal_to_js](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_to_js/6) which allows you to assign a drupal variable to a js variable. So you could get the result of `user_is_logged_in()` and store it as a js variable with `drupal_to_js()`.

Perhaps this variable can be set for some custom module's `hook_init()` to check on each page request of the user if he is logged in. There's no equivalent of settimeout in PHP that I know of but felt this option could also be considered. Hope it helps!

Answer (score -1):

Well you would need to make an AJAX call to a custom module where you would then call the php function and return the result.

So in a custom module that you already have, or create one otherwise:

```
function MODULENAME_menu() {
  $items = array();

  $items['user/logged_on'] = array(
    'title' => 'Ajax logincheck',
    'page callback' => 'MODULENAME_check_user_status',
    'access callback' => TRUE,
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK
  );

  return $items
}

function MODULENAME_check_user_status($uid) {
  // Do the lookup / checking
  // something like:
  if (user_is_logged_in()) {
    echo '1';
  else {
    echo $result;
  }
  exit();
}
```

replace `MODULENAME` with the name of your module, then make a jQuery ajax call to `/user/logged_on`. Which should return a 1 or a 0 to tell you if he's still logged in.

I am however not sure if you can access the $GLOBAL['user'] through an AJAX call, but worth a try.

**EDIT:** An example ajax call function would be something like this:

```
function checkUserStatus() {
     $.ajax({
        url: "/user/logged_on",
        complete: validateUser
    });
}

function validateUser(result) {
    if (result) {
        // User is logged in do what you need to do
    }
}
```

and I'm guessing you'll want to call `checkUserStatus` with the `setTimeout()` Method.

let me know if you need anything else...

Comment: This has me halfway there.  I've got code that echos the result (True or false) based on if the user is logged in.  I just can't seem to capture that returned result of True or False on the Javascript calling end.  I've tried embedding the result using a Drupal_add_js ('myModulename' => "array('loggedinstatus'=>'true')), 'setting'), but Drupal.settings.myModulename.loggedinstatus doesn't exist when i look for it in firebug or w/Javascript code after the call to PHP.  Could someone perhaps provide a JavaScript code snippet for receiving the variable or result from PHP?

Comment: Updated my answer with a quick and dirty javascript answer... I am not able to test it at the moment, but should give you an idea of what to do...